# Maximum likelihood estimate - help with calculating logs!

Tags: statistics, logarithms

I'm doing a practice question finding the maximum likelihood estimate, but I'm having a bit of trouble with the actual 'pure' maths bit of it (the differentiation)

I don't understand how you go from equation 1 to 3?

If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get from $(1)$ to $(2)$, You need to know that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\sigma} \log\sigma = \dfrac 1 \sigma$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\sigma} \, \dfrac{-1}{2\sigma^2} = \dfrac{-1}{2}\,\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\sigma} \sigma^{-2} = \dfrac{-1}{2}(-2)\sigma^{-3} = \dfrac{1}{\sigma^3}$.

**To get from $(1)$ to $(3)$:**
\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left( -n\log\sigma - \frac n 2 \log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - g(x_i))^2 \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & 0 + 0 - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} (y_i - g(x_i))^2. 
\end{align}

Then
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} (y_i-g(x_i))^2 = 2(y_i-g(x_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(y_i - g(x_i)).
$$

The we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} y_i - \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} g(x_i) = 0 - \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} g(x_i).
$$

That is what was done.  One can only presume that the fact that $g(x_i)$ depends on $\theta$ and $y_i$ does not was assumed to be already known to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

If we differentiate the RHS of equation 1 wrt to $\theta$, then the first two terms are zero. Inside the sum for the last term, we have by the chain rule, $\frac{\partial (y_i - g(x_i))^2}{\partial \theta} = -2(y_i - g(x_i)) \frac{\partial g(x_i)}{\partial \theta}$. (Here, I used the fact that $g$ is written as a function of $\theta$ as it says in your explanation.)

Hence, this gives, $-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum -2(y_i - g(x_i)) \frac{\partial g(x_i)}{\partial \theta} = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum (y_i - g(x_i)) \frac{\partial g(x_i)}{\partial \theta}$.